# XCode : How to Run Any Code Created in XCode on iDevice Without Creating Certificate One by One

Tags: ios, xcode

I have sucessfully run my code on my iPad this morning after creating some certificates on Apple developer's portal.

But when I create another project on XCode, it requires me to register that app on my developer account.

My question is very simple... Is it allowed to create certificate or whatever its name, so that I can run any code I created without registering App name over and over again. how to do that?

Thank you

Comment: It sounds like you are talking about provisioning profiles and App IDs. You might want to check out using wildcards. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ProvisioningStoreTechnologies/ProvisioningStoreTechnologies.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are creating a brand new project and you are not doing a distributing to itunes then I am very surprised that you are being prompted to register that app on itunesconnect. That doesn't make sense. I wonder if its a problem with your provisioning profile.

Anyways, look at the link above that people have already suggested. If that doesn't help then try this.

- Go to itunesconnect developer portal and create a new iOS app ID. The trick here is the app id has to be a * (astreisk) App name can be anything. Call it "MyTestApp2". This is the wildcard that people have suggested
- Now go to your provisioning profiles and create a iOS team provisioning profile as I did and making sure you select "MyTestApp2"
- Once you create this profile download it and on your computer and drag and drop it on XCode provisioning profile section.
- When you build another app on your ipad/iphone then this new provisioning profile will get copied on it.

[image]
[image]